# aws s3 cp with --include and --exculde does not copy anything

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have two buckets `bucket1` and `bucket2` in Amazon S3.

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket1 s3://bucket2  --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*am.dat"
```

does not copy any files from bucket1 though bucket1 has files that match pattern `*am.dat`.

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket1 s3://bucket2  --recursive
```

successfully copies all files to `bucket2`.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me! (On a Mac)

```
$ aws s3 mb s3://jzz1
make_bucket: jzz1

$ aws s3 mb s3://jzz2
make_bucket: jzz2

$ aws s3 cp x.json s3://jzz1/jam.dat
upload: ./x.json to s3://jzz1/jam.dat                          

$ aws s3 cp x.json s3://jzz1/gym.dat
upload: ./x.json to s3://jzz1/gym.dat                          

$ aws s3 cp s3://jzz1 s3://jzz2 --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*am.dat"
copy: s3://jzz1/jam.dat to s3://jzz2/jam.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when you run aws s3 cp with --recursive and --include or --exclude, it takes a while to run through all the directories. For example, if you have 10000 directories under the path that you are trying to lookup, it will have to go through all of them to make sure none of them match the the pattern that you provide.

This could take several minutes later (depending on how many directories you are trying to filter through) to see feedback if the pattern that you provide doesn't get processed till later.